# Best Practice to display text label on a .NetCore Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Is it best practice for **ALL** text on a .Net Core Razor webpage to be injected with Model Binding (Even on a static page), or should I only inject text which may need to change dynamically at runtime?

E.g. My `Index.cshtml` page has a `h1` title as per below. Is this considered bad practice or is it ok?

```
<h1 class="block-title-text" localize-content>A Fun Title</h1>
```

Thanks. Just trying to get my head around Razor and .Net Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if fine, in general you should keep user interface elements in the view (or the `.cshtml` file for Razor Pages). See [benefits of using views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#benefits-of-using-views) for more details, which among other things includes:

> The parts of the app are loosely coupled. You can build and update the app's views separately from the business logic and data access components. You can modify the views of the app without necessarily having to update other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised something which is obvious in hindsight. By injecting the strings using Model Binding instead of placing them into the HTML as above, it allows the incorporation of unit tests around those strings.